# CUDA plugin dlopen

Tags: cuda

I've written a cuda plugin (dynamic library), and I have a program written in C which uses dlopen() to load this plugin. I am using dlsym() to get the functions from this plugin. For my application it is very important that any time of loading plugin the program gets a new handle with dlopen() calling (the library file may modified subsequently).
Therefore after the using of functions from my plugin I invoke the dlclose(). The invocations dlopen() - dlsym() - dlclose() are occur during my program execution (in the loop).

If I working on the computer with NVIDIA driver 256.35 (CUDA 3.0 or 3.1) I have a memory leak (I use in my plugin cudaMemGetInfo() calling for the diagnostics).
If I working on the computer with NVIDIA driver 195.36.15 (CUDA 3.0) I have an error after some time of the program execution: “NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Too many open files).”

If I don't use the dlclose() invocation the program is working fine, but in this case I can't replace the plugin on a new one's during my program execution.

Anyone encountered this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody wrote plugins on CUDA?

I've found the similar example on CUDA SDK: `matrixMulDynlinkJIT`. I've done small correction in the code. In particular, in the file `cuda_drvapi_dynlink.c` I've corrected `cuInit()` function:

```
CUDADRIVER CudaDrvLib = NULL;

CUresult CUDAAPI cuInit(unsigned int Flags)

{

    //CUDADRIVER CudaDrvLib;

    CUresult result;
    int driverVer;

    if (CudaDrvLib != NULL) {
      dlclose (CudaDrvLib);
      CudaDrvLib = NULL;
    }
     .......
}
```

And in the file `matrixMulDynlinkJIT.cpp` I've added loop in the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

   printf("[ %s ]\n", sSDKsample);


    while (1) {
       // initialize CUDA

       CUfunction matrixMul = NULL;
       cutilDrvSafeCallNoSync(initCUDA(&matrixMul, argc, argv));

        .....

    }//while (1)
    cutilExit();
}
```

So, I have the same problem like in my program (after some time execution): “NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Too many open files).”
But when I comment out the `dlclose()` in the `cuda_drvapi_dynlink.c` file – all works fine

I can't understand this behavior...
Any ideas?